# Can I integrate two Angular 10 projects?

Tags: angular, mvvm, angular-components

I have a project called  College management system  , in that I have two modules and following its components.

> Staff

1. View Staff Members.
2. Add Staff Members.
3. Edit Staff Member details.

> Student

1. View Student Members.
2. Add Student Members.
3. Edit Student Member details.

When I click on Add Staff Members icon, can I call the UI from another angular 10  project called Staff management System, if so How to integrate two angular 10 projects.

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is to define the modular application, there is no need to make them in separated Angular projects, by using lazy loading and defining your different modules :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'staff', loadChildren: () => import(`./staff/staff.module`).then(m => m.StaffModule) },
{ path: 'student', loadChildren: () => import(`./student/student.module`).then(m => m.StudentModule) },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And this is example how you will define your Staff module :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { StaffRoutingModule } from './staff-module-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from '@shared/index';
import { CommonSharedModule } from '@modules/common/common.module';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [AddStaffComponent, EditStaffComponent ,ViewStaffComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    CommonSharedModule,
    StaffgModule,
  ],
  exports: []

})
export class StaffModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but i have a doubt , is that possible to call a component from another  project? Can i import external project ?

Comment: I think No, maybe if we are talking about micro-front end implementation maybe , if my answer help you please upvote

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call component by defining it in a routing and do a module wise routing.

Where the two modules have the path like
Staff and Students

Based on that routing on click of a button click set the route path to that module page and the same will be opened